# Replace element in numpy array using some condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements

For example, I have some array like:

```
>>> x = np.arange(-5, 4).reshape(3, 3)
>>> x
array([[-5, -4, -3],
       [-2, -1,  0],
       [ 1,  2,  3]])
```

How can I replace all elements with `b` which are greater then `a` otherwise set them to `0`?

I tried

```
np.place(x, lambda y: b if y > a else 0)
```

But it didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
x = np.arange(-5, 4).reshape(3, 3)
x
#array([[-5, -4, -3],
#       [-2, -1,  0],
#       [ 1,  2,  3]])

b = 1; a = 0;
np.where(x > a, b, 0)
#array([[0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0],
#       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: How can I just keep the same number in array if condition is true? (otherwize change it to `0`)

Comment: You can replace `b` with `x`. `np.where(x > a, x, 0)`, will pick values from `x` itself if condition is true. Or do it in place `x[x <= a] = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Not as good as `np.where` but in your case you could simply multiply the "boolean array" you get when you compare your array to `a` with `b`:

```
>>> x = np.arange(-5, 4).reshape(3, 3)
>>> a, b = 0, 6
>>> (x > a) * b
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [6, 6, 6]])
```

That works because `True` is equivalent to `1` and `False` to `0` in arithmetic operations.